# Replacing special characters (\n, \r, etc)

Tags: python

I have html source code that I get from a website using :

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
url = 'http://...'
html = str(urlopen(url).read())
```

Then I save this in a file doing like this :

```
with open('/file/path', 'w') as f:
    f.write(html)
```

When doing that, the new lines in the source code are replaced by `'\r\n'`.
I would like to know how to either delete those characters or replace them by their meaning (a new line, a tab, etc)

I tried to use `html.replace('\r\n', '\n')` but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you mean to write `html.replace('\r\n', '\n')`?

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: Or just `html.replace('\r', '')` or `html.translate(None, '\r')` ;-)

Comment: yes thanks, but f.replace('\r\n', '') did not work neither

Comment: @masero: how are you determining that `\r\n` characters are written?

Comment: No, no, don't call `f.replace`. Try `html.replace`.

Comment: @unutbu Oh yes sure, sorry I'm starting to be tired...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read()` on an `http.client.HTTPResponse` (as you get from `urllib.request.urlopen`) returns a `bytes` object. You cannot simply convert this to a `str` using `str(your_bytes_object)` as this converts `\r\n` (prints as a newline) into `\\r\\n` (the encoded form that actually prints as `\r\n` and not as a newline):

```
>>> a_bytes_object = b'This is a test\r\nMore test'
>>> str(a_bytes_object)
"b'This is a test\\r\\nMore test'"
>>> print(str(a_bytes_object))
b'This is a test\r\nMore test'
```

Instead, you must decode the given `bytes` object using `bytes.decode(your_encoding)`. `latin-1` usually works as an encoding if you just need to decode it into a string for writing to a file:

```
>>> a_bytes_object.decode("latin-1")
'This is a test\r\nMore test'
>>> print(a_bytes_object.decode("latin-1"))
This is a test
More test
```

Instead of using `decode`, you can also pass the encoding to `str` as a second argument, i.e.
`str(a_bytes_object, "latin-1")`
instead of
`a_bytes_object.decode("latin-1")`

Alternatively, you could simply open the file in binary mode (`open('/file/path', 'wb')`) and write the bytes object to it.

```
with open('/file/path', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(html)
```

You could also try to read the `Content-Type` header (something like `text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1`) to extract the charset and then decode to the proper string, but this is risky as it will not always work (not all servers send the header, not all include the encoding, not all encodings are supported by Python, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I reckon you're treating `replace` as something that modifies the string directly, as oppose to returns something that you need to assign to a new variable.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
url = 'http://www.google.com'
html = str(urlopen(url).read())

html_2 = html.replace('\r','')

with open('/file/path/filename.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(html_2)
```